# How to show sequential dialog popups?

Tags: android, popup

I'm having some  trouble with displaying multiple popups. Right now I have an AlertDialog that pops up with an EditView for the user to put in the name of the file they want to make, which I would then pass into a File object and then a Writer and a new Dialog is supposed to pop up asking the user if they want to launch the music player.

However, as things are now, after I press 'Ok' on the first AlertDialog, absolutely nothing happens. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help? Here is my code.

```
    //naming the playlist
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alert.setTitle("Exporting Playlist");
    alert.setMessage("Enter the name of the playlist!");

    // Set an EditText view to get user input 
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    alert.setView(input);

    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            name = input.getText().toString() + ".m3u";
            popup = true;
      }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        // Canceled.
      }
    });

    alert.show();


    //after the playlist is named, put songs into file
    if (popup){
        popup = false;
        final File list = new File(mp3folderPath + name);
        FileWriter writer;
        BufferedWriter write;

        ArrayList<String> playlist = new ArrayList<String>();
        Log.d("poo", "mAdapter count: "+mAdapter.getCount());
        for (int i=0; i < mAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            playlist.add(mAdapter.getItem(i));
        }
        Log.d("poo", playlist.toString());

        //write the songs  to the m3u playlist
        writer = new FileWriter(list);
        write = new BufferedWriter(writer);
        for (int i = 0; i<playlist.size(); i++){
            String[] name = playlist.get(i).split(" : ");
            Log.d("poo", name[0]);
            write.append(name[0]+"\n");
        }
        write.close();

        //popup window
        CharSequence choices[] = new CharSequence[] {"Launch Music Player", "Quit"};

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Exported playlist!");
        builder.setItems(choices, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if (which == 0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MUSIC_PLAYER);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
                else {
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });
    builder.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: just a suggestion, why do you have to write the condition if(popup), can't you call a function which will do what is written in that condition, when the user clicks "ok"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show sequential popup, the conditions and code for consecutive popup(s) would have to be reachable from one to the other.
AlertDialog1 has to contain the code which would show AlertDialog2...

Try something like this:

```
    //naming the playlist
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

                alert.setTitle("Exporting Playlist");
                alert.setMessage("Enter the name of the playlist!");

                // Set an EditText view to get user input 
                final EditText input = new EditText(this);
                alert.setView(input);

                alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    //check if the name is not null
                        name = input.getText().toString() + ".m3u";
                    //Now instead of popup = true;
                 //call func to name the playlist and next dialog
                        callNextDialog();
                  }
                });

                alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    // Canceled.
                  }
                });

                alert.show();


                //after the playlist is named, put songs into file
        //      if (popup){
        //          popup = false;
        //          }

                  public void callNextDialog(){
final File list = new File(mp3folderPath + name);
                    FileWriter writer;
                    BufferedWriter write;

                    ArrayList<String> playlist = new ArrayList<String>();
                    Log.d("poo", "mAdapter count: "+mAdapter.getCount());
                    for (int i=0; i < mAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                        playlist.add(mAdapter.getItem(i));
                    }
                    Log.d("poo", playlist.toString());

                    //write the songs  to the m3u playlist
                    writer = new FileWriter(list);
                    write = new BufferedWriter(writer);
                    for (int i = 0; i<playlist.size(); i++){
                        String[] name = playlist.get(i).split(" : ");
                        Log.d("poo", name[0]);
                        write.append(name[0]+"\n");
                        write.close();
                      //popup window
            CharSequence choices[] = new CharSequence[] {"Launch Music Player", "Quit"};

                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                        builder.setTitle("Exported playlist!");
                        builder.setItems(choices, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                if (which == 0) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MUSIC_PLAYER);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
                                }
                                else {
                                    finish();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    builder.show();
                  }
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

AlertDialog.show() doesn't wait for the dialog to go away.  It returns immediately.  That means ALL of the logic of what to do after the user makes a choice has to go in the onClick function of the dialog's positive button.

Basically, everything in your if(popup) code needs to be in the onClick handler